# Why using variable does not work in node-cron in node-js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, node-cron

I am trying to use variables "hrs", "min", "sec" to perform a cron job but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var cron = require('node-cron');

router.get('/schedulesms',async(req,res)=>{
const {hrs,min,sec} = req.body ;


cron.schedule(`/${sec} /${min} /${hrs} * * *`, () => {
  console.log('running a task according to given hrs min sec ');
});

res.send("All okk!!!!");

})

module.exports = router ;
```

I am getting following error after hitting my API.

```
 throw new Error(`${patterns[0]} is a invalid expression for second`);
[1]               ^
[1]
[1] Error: /5 is a invalid expression for second
```

[after hitting api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwqfl.png)

Comment: It should be `*/${min} */${hrs} * * *`. Cron doesn't support seconds.

Comment: cron.schedule(`* /${min} /${hrs} * * *`, () => {
  console.log('running a task according to given hrs min sec ');
});- I have changed my code as this but there is still an error as: throw new Error(`${patterns[1]} is a invalid expression for minute`);
[1]               ^
[1]
[1] Error: /0 is a invalid expression for minute

Comment: You aren't even using the pattern I sent...